# Cannot run my Electron App without internet connection

Tags: node.js, sql-server-2012, electron

I have an Electron App which connects to an instance of a sql server(Microsoft SQL Server 2012) on my local machine using npm module **mssql**.The app works fine when connected to the internet, however I get the following error when offline.

"Failed to connect to DELL:undefined - getaddrinfo ENOENT DELL:48988"

following is the config:

var dbconfig = {

```
    server: 'DELL\\INSTANCENAME',
    database: 'myDB',
    user: 'username',
    password: 'password'
    port: 1433
};
```

I have also made sure of the following:

```
 1. TCP/IP protocol is enabled    

 2. SQL Server INSTANCE/Server Agent and Server Browser is enabled
```

Since what I'm building is a desktop app, I do not want any dependency with internet connection. Not sure what I'm missing.... please suggest.

Comment: Could you make use of an API that checks for an internet connection recursively and won't attempt to connect to the database unless one is present?

Comment: The requirement is more about developing an offline app which has nothing to do with internet connection.My database is locally placed in my laptop(SQL Server instance), my app just needs to access it which it is not able to do without an internet connection.cant figure out why does it need the internet at all ....